# Displaying Variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, web, increment

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
   <body>
     <button onclick="question++">Increment</button>
     <script>
        function test() {
          var question = 0;
        }
     </script>
  </body>  
</html>
```

Question: How can I display question as a number on a webpage.

Since the variable question is constantly changing, how can I display the question, but make it auto-update every time the Increment button is pressed.

I don't know if you understand or not, but hopefully someone does and helps :)
Thanks!

Comment: You can't do it like that, `question` is a local variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DO something like this --

```
var question = 0;

function test() {

 question++; 
 document.getElementById('q').innerHTML = question;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2dzML/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/WxzNN/

**HTML**

```
<button onclick="updateQuestion();">Increment</button>
<p id="questionText">Question 0</p>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var question = 0;

function updateQuestion() {
    question++;
    document.getElementById("questionText").innerHTML = "Question " + question;
}
```

The key being that `question` is being declared by you in `scope` of the function `test()`. You need to define it in a scope available to the javascript being run by your button: a global scope.

For info about javascript scope, see here:

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/01/what-you-need-to-know-about-javascript-scope/

Answer (score 0):

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
<div id = "question"></div>

var question = 0;
function myFunction() {
return $('#question').html(question++)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot increment out-of-scope variables like that, you would have to call a function, with the appropriate scope, that does that for you, as has been mentioned in the other answers.

What you can also do(not that I would suggest this over the other method) is modify the question-count text directly, without linking it to a variable.

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById('question').innerText++">Increment</button>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/3JUKf/1/)